# how to find probability cut off in logistic regression

Tags: regression, probability, logistic

how to find probability cut off in logistic regression. by considering the Sensitivity, specificity and accuracy on different cut off values.

```
cut off                      0.3    0.35    0.4      0.45      0.5   0.55
Sensitivity                 66.93%  57.48%  44.09%  30.71%  23.62%  18.90%
Specificity                 58.97%  72.16%  82.05%  87.18%  93.04%  95.24%
Accuracy                    61.50%  67.50%  70.00%  69.25%  71.00%  71.00%
```

In this case which cut off to choose.

Comment: 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55
Sensitivity 66.93%  66.93% 57.48% 44.09% 30.71% 23.62% 18.90%
Specificity 58.97%  58.97% 72.16% 82.05% 87.18% 93.04% 95.24%
Accuracy 61.50%  61.50% 67.50% 70.00% 69.25% 71.00% 71.00%

Comment: The choice of cut-off is based on what you what to achieve using this logistic regression model. Although this is oversimplifying things in a major fashion, I was taught this handy mnemonic: **Sp**in rules in, **Sn**out rules out, where sp stands for specificity and sn for sensitivity. Most importantly however, if you could add context about the goal of your study/research, and some information on what is in the model, a more applicable answer might be possible.

Comment: One seeks a cutoff when one does not understand optimal decision making.